# Getting multiple data from Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, hashmap, singleton

[image]

Above is my database in Firestore. As can be seen, there are 2 Strings and 2 (or more) Arrays as fields.

I will be fetching the data to convert the same into different graphs 
For ex: 1. Graph showing sum of all chapters of all users
        2. Graph showing sum of "chapter1" of all users.
        3. Graph showing averages of all chapters etc.,

These graphs will be in different activities based on the selection of the user and the calculations are done specific to that activity.

Now my issue is in accessing this data to use it in various activities.

I have tried the HashMap Map> to store phonenumb, chapter(x), and values of chapter(x) respectively.

Below is the code to access the data:

```
CollectionReference chemistry = db.collection("RESULTS").document("Summary").collection("ChemistryVII");
                chemistry
                        .whereEqualTo("school", "Test School")
                        .get()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                    Map<String, Object> map = document.getData();
                                    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                                        if (entry.getKey().contains("chapter")) {
                                            if (outer.isEmpty() || !outer.containsKey(map.get("phonenumb"))) {
                                                Map<String, Object> inner = new HashMap<>();
                                                inner.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                                                String phonenumb = map.get("phonenumb").toString();
                                                outer.put(phonenumb, inner);
                                            } else {
                                                Map<String, Object> inner = new HashMap<>();
                                                inner.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                                                String phonenumb = map.get("phonenumb").toString();
                                                outer.put(phonenumb, inner);
                                            }

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                //Toast("Outer Details  " + outer);
                                schoolGraph();
                            }
                        });
```

However, this will not work as there could be multiple entries for the given key (phonenumb).

Trying to understand the best way to access such data and use it for multiple activities.

Comment: Does the phonenumb belong to the student or the school? You say there will be multiple entries with the same phone number. could you give a second example showing this

Comment: Hi Philip,
The phonenumb belongs to the student. 
To answer your next question, as the student attempts more than one chapter, the database will have multiple arrays for each student. 
for example., Chapter1=[10,5,5,7,7,8], Chapter2=[10,5,5,7,7,8], Chapter3=[5, 6, 4,3,6,7] and so on.
So while the inner Map will have k:Chapter1, v:[10,5,5,7,7,8]; k:Chapter2, v:[10,5,5,7,7,8] etc, the outer Map key will be a repeat of the phonenumb (k:5100351003);
Hence looking for alternate solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hash map key is unique. Every time you add a new Object with the same key, the old valude with the same key will be overwritten.

I think the logic in this part is correct:

```
if (outer.isEmpty() || !outer.containsKey(map.get("phonenumb"))) {
    Map<String, Object> inner = new HashMap<>();
    inner.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    String phonenumb = map.get("phonenumb").toString();
    outer.put(phonenumb, inner);
```

You insert in the inner map the first chapter sum. Because the outer map does not have the key `phonenumb`, you need to insert in the outer map too.

However in the `else` part:

```
Map<String, Object> inner = new HashMap<>();
inner.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
String phonenumb = map.get("phonenumb").toString();
outer.put(phonenumb, inner);
```

You do not need the `outer.put(phonenumb, inner);`, because inner exists already and has the sum of a chapter.

Here the outer has the key 'phonenumber', you just have to insert to the inner map the new entry sum:  `inner[chapter] = sum` .

You need something like `outert[phonenumb][chapter] = sum`